# Обособляется ли сравнение?

Tags: пунктуация

"Вокруг носились (,) как на пожаре (,) служанки".
Нужны ли тут запятые? И почему?

Answer (score 2):

Да, запятые нужны, потому что союз КАК в вашем примере вводит обстоятельство, выраженное сравнительным оборотом. Поэтому пишем: *Вокруг носились, как на пожаре, служанки*.